# Free GUI graphing program for macOS to program to generate logarithmic line plots

Tags: osx, gui, graphs, macos

I am looking for a free **GUI** program I can use to graph straight lines `y = ax + b` with

- linear `x` and `y` axes
- logarithmic `x` and linear `y` axes
- logarithmic `x` and logarithmic `y` axes

I have done so with matplotlib and Python, but now I'm interested in doing this with a pure GUI program running under macOS. I had a look at [geogebra](https://www.geogebra.org/), but couldn't figure out how to do logarithmic axes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Grapher.app](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grapher) has been installed by default with all versions of Mac OS since 10.4 and does what you are asking for and much more (like 3D graphs). You should find it in the Applications/Utilities folder.

**Edit:** While linear-linear, log-log and linear X - log Y are easy, I'm not sure how to do log X - linear Y with Grapher. I'll report back when I learn more. Otherwise you could always use Numbers which likewise comes with your Mac.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly! Log-Lin is possible too via Menu _Format_ --> _Coordinate System..._